# ASP.NET + memcached - where and when should I check for conditions to invalidate data?

Tags: asp.net, memcached

I am concerned about how and when to check for conditions that warrant invalidating data in the cache.

I'm thinking in terms of e-commerce product listing or user-profile information.

Should this be done with a separate service that runs periodically that checks for old or changed data?

Should we rely on database triggers to let us know when updates or inserts occur?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to use the Sql Dependency implementation on the cache. Check out this article...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx